# Stream - Reset vs Allocating a new stream?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, io, stream

I'm using an input stream to read multiple files, and to be precise, a ByteArrayInputStream in a sperate thread. I use a while loop for this, should I create a new ByteArrayInputStream each iteration, or should I reset and read again?

Comment: it is not clear what the connection is between the files you are trying to read and the bytearrayinputstream in the other thread. as Rembo said: show code

Comment: I would question the whole design. Read the files in the thread that processes them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a performance test on this and the latter is a bit faster than the former. If you need to have a faster code execution, reset the stream instead of creating a new one in a while loop.

Comment: In the case of large files could this not be an issue? If the file is large and you set a mark you may miss your mark on the reset.

Comment: If I'm deciding between a reset or a new stream, it means that the old stream is no longer needed. This isn't an issue for me, but it might for someone else.